# How to control Loading panel using master page and without using AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, page-loading-message

I have an asp.net project and I want to show the progress image (GIF) **without using AJAX** and using simple java-script DIV magic.

All I want to do is to put one div (which show animation clock while page loading in progress) in master page (asp.net master page so I need not to repeat the code on every content pages) and show it when page load is in progress.

I hope your understand what I want to do.

Thanks,

Comment: To clarify: That one div contains just some generic "loading, please wait..." string, or like you said, a spinning clock GIF? Also, you mention "master" page - do you mean that there are "clone" pages? As in...clone windows?

Comment: I have updated question to justify your clarifications.

Comment: something like this but not this one as this is somewhat not complete one.....http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1633/full-screen-loading-panel/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this

```
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" onLoad="init()">


    <div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:163px; text-align:center;top:310px; left:487px;">
    <img src="images/loading.gif" border=0 style="margin:38px"/>
</div>
 <script>
 var ld=(document.all);
  var ns4=document.layers;
 var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
 var ie4=document.all;
  if (ns4)
    ld=document.loading;
 else if (ns6)
    ld=document.getElementById("loading").style;
 else if (ie4)
    ld=document.all.loading.style;
  function init()
 {
 if(ns4){ld.visibility="hidden";}
 else if (ns6||ie4) ld.display="none";
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: you put this code in masterpage and on body **onload** call function **init()** The div with id **loading** is area where u put gif loading image.just below that u will find function which control visiblity of image with div.

Answer (score 0):

make 2 sections in your document's body

```
<div id="progress">
// Code for gif image
</div

<div id="content" style="display:none;">
// Whole page content
</div>
```

And after that include this javascript. Not in header

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("progress").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

If you know jQuery you can do similarly on $(document).ready() event